# Set a FILL_PARENT width to a TextView, which is inside of a TableRow

Tags: android, textview, width, tablerow, fill-parent

I have a TextView inside of the [TableRow](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/TableRow.html). Is there any way to set a FILL_PARENT width to this TextView?

**Edited: Doesn't FILL when I have a backgroundImage to the TableRow**

```
<TableLayout android:id="@+id/tableLayout1"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent" android:layout_height="fill_parent"
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
    <TableRow android:layout_height="wrap_content" android:id="@+id/tableRow1"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent" android:background="@drawable/myImage">
        <TextView android:text="I wrapped!" android:id="@+id/textView1"
            android:layout_width="fill_parent" android:background="@color/white"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"></TextView>
    </TableRow>
</TableLayout>
```

Answer (score 1):

Your [link](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/TableRow.html) answers your question.

> The children of a TableRow do not need to specify the layout_width and
>   layout_height attributes in the XML file. TableRow always enforces
>   those values to be respectively MATCH_PARENT and WRAP_CONTENT

`FILL_PARENT` (renamed `MATCH_PARENT` in API Level 8 and higher)

Your `TextView` should automatically be `FILL_PARENT` which is `MATCH_PARENT`.

Comment: @coffee: Oh, I see what you're saying now.  Thanks for the edit.

Comment: I just replace all my TableRows by LinearLayout. Works fine